# How to name a class that populate select lists in the view model

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, naming-conventions

I have view model class

```cs
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public int ListOneId { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> ListOne { get; set; }

    public int ListTwoId {get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> ListTwo { get; set; }

    public int ListThreeId {get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> ListThree { get; set; }

    public int ListFourId {get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> ListFour { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

I can populate the view model in the controller class

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new IndexViewModel();

    model.ListOne = _context.ListOne
        .Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Text = x.Text, Value = x.Value })
        .ToList()

    // ...

    return View(model);
}
```

But because the view model populating appears in multiple places, I would like to encapsulate it into its own class.

The question is, what is the suitable name for such a class?

It's not a builder, it's not a factory. Is it seeder, populator or helper? What common suffix can be used here?

Or should it be part of the `ViewModel` itself (for example with a method that has `DbContext` as an parameter)?

### Update

The question is not about how to name the `SelectList Provider` but instead where to populate the view model (which class to call this SelectList provider from, whether it's repository, factory, DbContext or else) to minimize duplicates.

Comment: repository ?  with GetList1/GetList2/... methods ... which can be injected via DI and  with  context as constructor parameter which also would be injected

Comment: @Selvin, so you would populate the view model within the view model?

Comment: no, it would be `ListRepository` some interface like `IListRepository` and no other base class

Comment: @Selvin so `ListRepository` will accept and populate view model?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest if you add a factory method then it easily becomes a factory pattern. That's what I would do personally

```cs
public static List<SelectListItem> GetTheList(int id) =>
    id switch
    {
        1 => ListOne,
        2 => ListTwo
        //...
        _ => throw new Exception("Please select a valid list")
    };

//use it like:
List<SelectListItem> list = IndexSelectListFactory.GetTheList(1); //gets ListOne
```

Notice I have named it IndexSelectListFactory here, just add the suffix that matches the pattern you end up choosing, in this case "-Factory"

But if you do not want to do this, then just keep it simple like "IndexSelectLists"

Comment: Thank you, but where do you call these `IndexSelectListFactory.GetTheList(1)` methods, if you need to populate view model in multiple places? The class provides the SelectLists but does not assign them to the model.

Comment: @Muflix well a factory pattern is for returning things dynamically, I wouldn't recommend creating a "setter factory" of sorts. These are public properties so I would recommend using its setters to go about that, in the name of clean code at least. That being said, you should go with something like "IndexSelectLists" because in this case of needing to access and mutate the lists its not really a factory pattern in itself, although it can keep the factory method I provided above